# iPhone: How can I use gcov?

Tags: iphone, gcov, google-toolbox-for-mac

I'm trying to use gcov on iPhone Project
 and followed Apple's instruction described [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2007/qa1514.html), but it doesn't work.

When I build and go configured project, .gcda file is created for each object file.
But no executed lines are recorded to .gcda files. (CoverStory shows all coverages are 0%)

I just added a simple class to template project as following.

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
- (void)func1:(BOOL)flag;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (void)func1:(BOOL)flag {
  if (flag) {
    NSLog(@"flag is YES");
  }
  else {
    NSLog(@"flag is NO");  
  }
}
@end
```

I allocated this class and call func1 in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, 
and I expected that coverage of SomeClass is showed (50% or so).

I'm using OSX 10.6.4, iPhone SDK 4.0 and Xcode 3.2.3.
Some more configurations are needed? Please guide.

UPDATE 2010/7/15:

I tried these hints in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385568/why-doesnt-gcov-report-any-lines-being-covered-by-my-unit-tests) @tonclon gave me, but it didn't work yet.
In the following description is what I tried.

1. Cocoa Application compiled by GCC 4.0
   In project settings of "Cocoa" Application,

   - set GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS to YES
   - set GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES to YES
   - set Other Linker Flag to -lgcov
   - set C/C++ Compiler Version to 4.0

   It worked, .gcda files were generated with coverage information as expected.
   In iPhone project with SDK 4.0, however, I can't use same configuration because
   gcc 4.0 can't compile some syntax in SDK 4.0 (ex Blocks)
2. using custom gcov library in google-tool-box
   Instead of setting -lgcov in Other Linker Flag,
   I tried [custom gcov library included in google-toolbox-for-mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/SnowLeopardGCov),
   but generated .gcda files shows coverage is 0%. (same result)

Can you please tell me what I should do next? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed all hints given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385568/why-doesnt-gcov-report-any-lines-being-covered-by-my-unit-tests

Comment: @tonclon Thank you very much for your information, I tried these hints in that link, but it didn't work yet.. I'm updating my question.
Can you please tell me more hints about this issue?

Comment: Somewhat unhelpful, but gcov is no longer supported; we gave up on using it.

Comment: @tc Where do you know that from? Please give a link and consider to answer instead commenting, can't award the bounty to an comment.

Comment: You want coverage on which language?  ObjectiveC? C?

Comment: @Ira Baxter Thank you for your comment, I want to measure Objective-C's code coverage.

Comment: @taichino: Ah.  I might have been help if it had been conventional C. Can't help with objective C.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. Turn off prefix headers
2. Make sure you quit "correctly"

Please check out the gcov pages here (http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/w/list) and see if they help at all. I have gcov working with Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS4.2.